# mysql - Counting repetition of numbers in column from 0 to max

Tags: mysql

i am new to MySQL.

I have a table with column [Values] with integers.

I want to create a table with two columns:

```
  Value - Each value between 0 and max(Values)

  ValCount - The total count of the value
```

Example:

input:

```
ValuesTables = [1,1,2,5]
```

Expected output:

```
[[0,0],[1,2],[2,1],[3,0],[4,0],[5,1]]
```

To create the data use:

```
Create table ValuesTable (Val int);
INSERT INTO ValuesTable
(Val) VALUES (1),(1),(2),(5);
```

i have done the following:

```
Select Val,count(Val)
from ValuesTable
group by Val;
```

But i am not getting the non existing values 0,3,4 in the output.

Thanks

Comment: Your input and output aren't tables. Do you have/want strings like that? [Edit] the question and provide a proper [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables (paste the **text**, don't use images), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Also show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

You need a table with all the possible values, left join the values to that and then do the aggregation. In MySQL 8+ you can use a recursive CTE.

```
WITH
RECURSIVE cte
AS (
SELECT 0 n
UNION ALL
SELECT n + 1
       FROM cte
       WHERE n + 1 <= (SELECT max(val)
                              FROM ValuesTable)
)
SELECT cte.n,
       count(v.val)
       FROM cte
            LEFT JOIN ValuesTable v
                      ON v.val = cte.n
       GROUP BY (cte.n);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c4e5b3c8f9bc19c0ce24f574d196dec2)